# Diffrence between .load() and $.get()

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating a mobile app with multiple HTML pages, jquery and Phone gap. I didn't wanted to copy paste same footer in my app's pages redundantly so I created a global footer.html and tried to load that file's content on documents .ready() something like this.

**Footer HTML**

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-grid="d">
    <ul class="apple-navbar-ui comboSprite">
        <li><a href="../dashboard.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../contacts/contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="../applications/applications.html">Applications</a></li>
        <li><a href="settings.html">My Account</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Main HTML**

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="footer" data-role="footer">
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#footer').load("footer.htm");
   $('#footer').trigger('create');
});
```

It loads the content of footer.html but the Jquery mobile's UI doesn't get rendered.

But when I changed document ready code to this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.get('footer.htm', function (retData) {
      $('#footer').append(retData);
      $('#footer').trigger('create');
   });
});
```

It worked great.

So what's the difference between these two approach ? and why did one worked and another one failed ?

Comment: (offtopic) You're not concerned how search engines will look at your page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the difference is that in your `$.get()` you have a callback function and you put there the `$('#footer').trigger('create');` while in the `.load()` you didn't put a callback function.

You should've done this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#footer').load("footer.htm", function(){
        $(this).trigger('create');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah that worked, Does it mean that `.load()` is slower than `.append()` because `.load()` retrieves the data from external file first and then appends that data into element ?? and I guess `.load()` is asynchronous too that's why `.trigger('create')` called before loading of content. Can I make it synchronous ??

Comment: I think `ajax` requests are asynchronous. I have no idea how to make it synchronous [This](http://api.jquery.com/load/) might help you answer your questions.

Answer (score 4):

Difference between methods:  
`.get()` - loads ALL content 
`.load()` - can be load partial content `$('#result').load('file.html #container');`

Answer (score 0):

.load() - simplest way to fetch data from server, however unlike .get() method,allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted.
like "`$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );`"

.get() - load data from the server using a HTTPGET request.loads all the content from the sever.